# Increment a counter while iterating through a foreach loop

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to increment k after each time that ShowNote() method is invoked so that each note is displayed in sequenced. I have tried to place k++ but somehow it is not working.
I have placed a textbox to see if the value of k is actually incrementing but it is always the same and therefore the images are being placed on each other and not in sequence.

How can i solve this issue please...

```
  private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] xLoc = {0,70,140,210,280,350,420};
        int k = 0;
        int yLoc = 50;
        foreach (MusKey mk in this.panel2.Controls)
        {
            if (sender == mk)
            {

                textBox1.Text = "Key No. " + mk.musicNote.ToString() + " pressed";
                MusicNote musNote = new MusicNote(mk.musicNote,"Crotchet.bmp");
                musNote.PlaySound();
                this.panel3.Controls.Add(musNote);
                musNote.ShowNote("", xLoc[k], yLoc); 
                k++;
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k); //Done for testing.. too see if k      is incrementing....
                musNote.BringToFront();
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: also u should have k and xLoc outside this function, at class level. the only thing is suspect is that the foreach -if is executed only once (for any mk==sender) when the function is called again, the value is reinitialized to 0 at int k=0.

Comment: Issue is resolved.. i just placed the k and xLoc outside the method and that worked fine. As you said the value of k was being set to 0 each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private int[] xLoc = {0,70,140,210,280,350,420};
   private int k = 0;

 private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int yLoc = 50;
        foreach (MusKey mk in this.panel2.Controls)
        {
            if (sender == mk)
            {

                textBox1.Text = "Key No. " + mk.musicNote.ToString() + " pressed";
                MusicNote musNote = new MusicNote(mk.musicNote,"Crotchet.bmp");
                musNote.PlaySound();
                this.panel3.Controls.Add(musNote);
                musNote.ShowNote("", xLoc[k], yLoc); 
                k=k>=xLoc.Length-1? xLoc.Length:k++; // so that k does not point to non existent location
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(k); //Done for testing.. too see if k      is incrementing....
                musNote.BringToFront();
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I have replaced the array with an int k = 0 ... the after invoking ShowNote() I just increment k by 70 so that I do not run out of bounds.